# How do I declare and assign an object for this line of code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm having difficulty understanding the concept of declaring an object within code...

The following code is part of a worksheet change event, which directs the user to "F6" when the user attempts to select any of the three "FILLABLE" name ranges established on sheet1 of my workbook.
I consolidated this code from several working if statements using the "union" function and now I'm receiving run-time error '424' whenever I run my macro.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory in-out")

If target.Row < 14 And Intersect(target, Union(FILLABLE_TOP_MER, FILLABLE_TOP_REG, FILLABLE_TOP_NOMSG)) Is Nothing Then
    Range("F6").Select
```

Comment: Is `target` declared and assigned anywhere? You should provide more code in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: FYI error 424 means 'Object Required'. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-required-error-424

Comment: Always put `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, that will prevent the code from compiling with undeclared variables. You're getting error 424 "Object Required" because `target` is an undeclared variable (and thus a `Variant/Empty`) against which a member call is not possible, because it's not an object and as such, doesn't have any members to invoke.

Comment: "The following code is part of a worksheet change event" - so `Target` should already be declared in that context?

Comment: `FILLABLE_TOP_MER` etc are what exactly?  If not range objects then that's a problem you need to fix.

Comment: @TimWilliams ah, missed that. Guessing `FILLABLE_XXXXX` aren't objects then. They should be `Range` instances; OP needs to [edit] and show us how `FILLABLE_XXXXXX` variables (constants?) are being declared+assigned.

Answer (score 3):

`Union` works with `Range` objects. Assuming `FILLABLE_TOP_MER` is a `String` containing the name of a `Name`, then you need to get the `Range` for these names:

```
Dim FillableTopMerRange As Range
Set FillableTopMerRange = ThisWorkbook.Names(FILLABLE_TOP_MER).RefersToRange

Dim FillableTopRegRange As Range
Set FillableTopRegRange = ThisWorkbook.Names(FILLABLE_TOP_REG).RefersToRange

'...

If ... And Intersect(Target, Union(FillableTopMerRange, FillableTopRegRange, ...)) Is Nothing Then...
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone that provided input, but this solved my problem perfectly! Thank you, Mathieu!